# Make a java color less dark?

Tags: java, swing, colors

I know Color has a `darker()` method that returns a darker version of a color. Is there a way to change the factor (I believe it is 0.7) in which Color does so, thereby making a Color less/more dark (or conversely, less/more bright)?

From the Java API:

> This method applies an arbitrary scale factor to each of the three RGB components of this Color to create a darker version of this Color.

In other words, can I change this arbitrary scale factor?

Comment: modify the RGB components yourself, it's just a convenience method

Comment: Why not modify the color your self by any factor? Isn't that just easier.

Comment: why not read the source code and change it to suit yourself

Comment: you specialize in easy questions so everyone can get their points... ah see what your doin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javaAPI doesn't provide any utility for this. Anyways, it's pretty trivial, so why not code it yourself?

```
Color overrideBrightness(Color c , float factor){
    if(factor < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Factor must be positive");

    float[] components = c.getComponents();

    return new Color(Math.min(components[0] * factor , 1.0) , 
                     Math.min(components[1] * factor , 1.0) ,
                     Math.min(components[2] * factor , 1.0) , 
                     components[3]);
}
```

For `factor > 1`, the color becomes brighter, for `factor < 1`, the color becomes darker. This method should be reversible, except for some rounding-errors.

Note this method **doesn't** handle extreme cases, like overflow for `factor` close to `Float.MAX_VALUE` and won't work for perfect black (`new Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`).

Comment: I certainly can- I was just wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it. Thanks though

Comment: Consider checking boundary/edge conditions before creating a Color in that method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels might be a good idea. This was just a quick draft of how this can be done.